# windows service and visual web developer 2010 express

Tags: windows-services, visual-studio-express

I am using microsoft visual web developer 2010 express edition.

i want to create windows service but, the template is missing .

how can i install this missing template.

thanks  and regards

Mohit Leekha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Visual Basic (or C#) 2010 Express, not the Web version to build a Windows Service.

I made a template for Visual Studio 2010 Express you can get it at my blog: http://blog.larmib.com/2011/windows-service-template-for-visual-studio-2010-express/ it is for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2):

This is listed as a limitation within the Express Edition of Visual Studio 2010.  I'm sure you can do something not so ethical to get around it to build a template, you can google for that one.

Now, you can build a windows service without the template, you just will not have all of the fancy design time support for a few items.